# iOS: Push array to UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

Can you run me through the steps to push an array to a UITableview?

I'm new to Cocoa/Objective-C, so could you explain how the .m, .h work with the delegate?

Comment: Can you be more specific with 'push'? You want the table to show the array?

Comment: Yes, I want the table to show the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
@interface SomeInstance : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *theArray;
}

@end

@implementation SomeInstance


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Pineapple",@"Banana",nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [theArray count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Selected a row" message:[theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [theArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: This builds fine...I have a ListViewController.h&.m, and a secondview.xib. (This started as a navigation bar app). the nav buttons work fine, but there is still no table being rendered in the secondview.xib.  What am I missing?

Comment: The ListViewController is the file owner of the secondview? Did you set the class of the file owneer in IB? Did you then linked the delegate and the datasource?

Comment: If I drag a tableview to the secondview in IB, then link the datasource and delegate to the file owner, the program crashes when I tap the second view icon in the tab bar...

Comment: Stack in the console? What does it say? Try run and debug, when it crashes to to the debugger, you can exactly see where your program crashes. With only the given fact that it crashes, i cant help you.

Comment: Does "Incomplete Implementation of ListViewController.m" mean anything?

Comment: That means you must implement another method. These come in 2 warnings or more. Click the bottom left corner of xcode and you see your warnings. The second warning causes the 'Incomlete Implemetentation..' fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to ObjC, I would suggest starting with something more simple before diving into UITableViews.

(sorry if that's not what you want to hear, but I figure you'll be more productive in the long run).

To answer your specific question, A class that inherits from UITableViewControllerDelegate is expected to support various methods required by the UITableViewController protocol.